# Lord Buddha's First teaching and its meaning?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, suttas, four-noble-truths, middle-way

Can anybody provide a full translation of Lord Buddha's First teaching. I am referring to a Sutta called "Dhamma chakka pawaththana".

Comment: Why are you asking this question? There are several English translations of [Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.than.html) available at accesstoinsight.org.

Comment: Apparently he was searching for the terms given in his question 'Dhamma chakka pawaththana' and couldn't locate anything. This has happened to me as well. Since these are long names I think google also struggles if you don't search the correct word.

Comment: I get the link to Access to Insight on the first page when I google "Dhamma chakka pawaththana" (without quotes).

Comment: No need to be rude,it just came to mind and i thought a good friend would help!  : (  that's it and thanks for the link @michau  : )

Comment: Thank you for being reasonable @dmsp , i did not searched for it just asked from this group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the name of the sutta, and if it's a famous sutta, then I find you can easily find it using Google, for example:

- [This search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Dhamma+chakka+pawaththana) (Google)

Wikipedia too has many articles about Buddhism, and one of them describes this sutta:

- [Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhammacakkappavattana_Sutta) (Wikipedia)

At the end of the Wikipedia article are "External links" to translations and commentaries and so on:

- [External links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhammacakkappavattana_Sutta#External_links) (from Wikipedia)

This Buddhism.SE site's [Help page](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) includes a list of "Useful resources", one section of which is "Buddhist Texts", which includes several anthologies of suttas.

Looking in each of the collections mentioned in our list of "Useful resources", I found the following (seven) links to the sutta you asked for:

- **[Setting in Motion the Wheel of the Dhamma](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn56.11)** (SuttaCentral)
- Four translations, on Access to Insight:

  - **[Translated by Peter Harvey](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.harv.html)**
  - **[Translated by Ñanamoli Thera](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.nymo.html)**
  - **[Translated by Piyadassi Thera](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.piya.html)**
  - **[Translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.than.html)**
- **[Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/samyutta/maha/sn56-011.html)** (Buddha Vacana)
- **[The Discourse on the Turning of the Wheel of Truth](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.1-Dhammacakka-Pavattana-S-s56.11-piya.pdf)** (Dharmafarer, PDF)